# How to populate multiple fields with the time in HTML form using a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a VERY extensive HTML form for collecting data during a complex manufacturing process. The data collection requires users to stamp the date and time in perhaps 80 separate fields - and I am using buttons as labels for each of the data fields.

I have a JavaScript function which gives me the desired results for an individual field - but I don't want to have to duplicate the code for the function and change the name for each required entry.

I'm a novice at Javascript and only a beginner at HTML - but I know this can be done... I just can't figure out how. I know it has to do with passing the ID tag for my HTML fields (into a loop?) to be used as variables in the code... but I'm not clear on how.

Here's the code I'm thinking of using for my timestamp (setup for 1 field):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getClockTime()
{
   var now    = new Date();
   var hour   = now.getHours();
   var minute = now.getMinutes();
   var second = now.getSeconds();
   if (hour   < 10) { hour   = "0" + hour;   }
   if (minute < 10) { minute = "0" + minute; }
   if (second < 10) { second = "0" + second; }
   var timeString= hour +
                    ':' +
                    minute +
                    ':' +
                    second
document.getElementById("txtTime").value = timeString;
}
</script>
```

If someone can give me a clue about how to approach this I'd sure appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if you modify your JS function to return a value, you can call it more than once and reuse the code.  So substitute:

```
document.getElementById("txtTime").value = timeString;
```

for

```
return timeString;
```

Then, as you have jQuery available, you can iterate through the fields that need dates.  If you give them a class of "dateField" (for example), i.e. `<input class="dateField" type="text" name="whatever" />` , you can then do:

```
$(".dateField").val(getClockTime());
```

**EDIT:** other answer correctly points out that calling getClockTime() is unnecessarily intensive (it also will potentially get you different times).  So, as suggested, a more fool-proof and better performing version:

```
theTime=getClockTime();
$(".dateField").val(theTime);
```

Comment: please see the above comment to theftprevention regarding more details of my issue.  Thanks so much for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery (which I recommend you do for a task like this, especially since you tagged the question as "jquery"), you can use the following:

```
function getClockTime()
{
    var now    = new Date();
    var hour   = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var second = now.getSeconds();
    if (hour   < 10) { hour   = "0" + hour;   }
    if (minute < 10) { minute = "0" + minute; }
    if (second < 10) { second = "0" + second; }
    var timeString= hour +
                    ':' +
                    minute +
                    ':' +
                    second
    return timeString;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var time = getClockTime();
    $("input.needsTime").val(time);
});
```

Then, for every `input` that needs a time inserted, simply use:

```
<input type="text" name="whatever" class="needsTime" />
```

See [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k2VdP/).

Your original `getClockTime` function is used to get the current time. Then, when the document is done loading, this function is set to the variable `time` so it doesn't have to be called more than one (saves a bunch of calculations and performance). Finally, jQuery cycles through all `input` elements with the class `needsTime` and sets their values accordingly.

Comment: My apologies for being unclear. The timestamp for each of the fields will be at different times. there is a button which will call for the currenttime and post this in a field near the button (each field has it's own button) with a related id (i.e.: time1 for button and time1Fld for the field) I'm thinking I can use the above mentioned code on a "onclick" call from my button and use a variable to add the :Fld" onto the id from the button to 'post' the return to the appropriate field.  Hope this clarifies things - and thank you very much for your responses... it's helped!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this works - rather well:

```
<!-- Posts current time (HH:MM:SS) into a field with same id + "Time" as the button.
Each button must have an id value and onclick="inserttime(this.id)" -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function inserttime(butID) {
var timeFLD = (butID+"Time")
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()
  if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0" + minutes}
  if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0" + seconds}
  pTime= hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " "
document.getElementById(timeFLD).value = pTime
}
</script>
```